# SQL Union All is too slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, union

I am rewriting an old legacy system. It has a function called `checkExisting()`. The old system was using queries for extracting objects from the MSSQL database like this (with ADO DB):

```
SELECT ObjectId, Name..... 
FROM tblRegisteredIncludes   
WHERE UPPER("Name") IN ('PROGA.H', 'PROGB.H'...............  list)
```

There are many tables like `tblRegisteredIncludes` but SQLs are grouped by the tablename and are using the IN clause with list of object names.

This is executing properly fast because SQL Server collects all objects in one scan and there was an index over the `Name` column in the table.

However, in the new system, I can not use the same SQL because the `WHERE` condition is more complex. It is also using a Source field and sometimes and other fields in the condition. I have a larger number of single SQL queries:

```
SELECT ObjectId, Name..... FROM tblRegisteredIncludes   
WHERE UPPER("Name") = 'PROGA.H' AND UPPER("Source") = "..."

SELECT ObjectId, Name..... FROM tblRegisteredIncludes   
WHERE UPPER("Name") = ('PROGB.H') AND UPPER("Source") = "..."
```

I have replaced the Name-Index in `tblRegisteredIncludes` table with a composite index over `(Name,Source)`.

I have expected even so the total SQLs execution to be a little slower but with no more than 15-20%. Instead it is much, much slower, sometimes up to 100%. I tried to combine the SQLs in a single large SQL query using UNION ALL:

```
SELECT ObjectId, Name..... FROM tblRegisteredIncludes   
WHERE UPPER("Name") = 'PROGA.H' AND UPPER("Source") = "..."
UNION ALL
SELECT ObjectId, Name..... FROM tblRegisteredIncludes   
WHERE UPPER("Name") = ('PROGB.H') AND UPPER("Source") = "..."
```

and then pocessing the resulting ADO DB recordset later but it is even slower!

I need to know whether there is some efficient way to execute these queries faster? I need to reach performance similar to the old case when using IN clause and a list of names. I can provide the execution plan.

Comment: I would like to see the execution plan. And why do you use `upper`? Have you checked that the collation is case-sensitive?

Comment: Can you elaborate on " I can not use the same SQL because the WHERE condition is more complex.", in the example you have given there is no reason the queries need to be separate.

Comment: Do you really need the UPPER? Case-sensitive collations are seldom used for this very reason. The use of UPPER ruins your query plan, because the function is opaque to SQL Server - It doesn't know what the function does so it won't use the index and do table scans instead.

Comment: Using Upper on both sides can be one of the problems: WHERE UPPER("Name") = ('PROGB.H') AND UPPER("Source") = "..."... In Oracle one can create function based index when converting to Upper/Lower. Not sure if same thing possible in SQL Server.

Comment: What does "SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('<YourDatabaseName>', 'Collation')" give as result?

Comment: OK, more to the point: What does "SELECT name, collation_name FROM sys.columns WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('tblRegisteredIncludes') AND name IN ('Name', 'Source')" give as result?

Comment: Since you're rebuilding the system, I'd consider changing case policies altogether, or adding `lcName` and `lcSource` columns and keep them up-to-date via triggers with the lowercase version of the original columns; then indexing on them. **If** the cardinality of the Name and Source set is low enough compared to the number of rows in your table, and you use the name as is (you never query for "sources beginning with S"), you could consider replacing those columns with mapping tables, and using their IDs in the query.

Comment: @lserni surely PERSISTED computed columns would be better than keeping columns updated via a trigger? e.g. `CREATE TABLE T (A VARCHAR(50) COLLATE Latin1_general_cs_as NOT NULL, B AS A COLLATE Latin1_general_ci_as PERSISTED, C AS LOWER(A) PERSISTED)`

Comment: Also, I noticed that if your compound index is on (Name,Source), the optimizer cannot use this because it cannot index Name.  Either an index on (Source) or (Source,Name) will speed up your current results.

Comment: @GarethD, good point. On SQL Server 2005+, that would surely be an option, and easier to maintain, if a case insensitive collation is not acceptable or a more complicated match might be needed.

Answer (score 3):

In the `union all` version, each subquery is resulting in a separate scan of the table.

You should be bringing in all the rows using `or` conditions:

```
SELECT ObjectId, Name.....
FROM tblRegisteredIncludes   
WHERE (UPPER("Name") = 'PROGA.H' AND UPPER("Source") = "...") or
      (UPPER("Name") = ('PROGB.H') AND UPPER("Source") = "...") or
      . . .
```

If you have a situation where all the comparisons are on `Name` and `Source`, I would suggest creating a table-on-the-fly using a CTE:

```
with toinclude as (
   select 'PROGA.H' as name, 'SOURCE' as source union all
   select . . .
)
select ri.ObjectId, ri.Name
from tblRegisteredIncludes join
     toinclude
     on ri.name = toinclude.name and ri.source = toinclude.source
```

You can leave out the `toupper()` unless you are specifically concerned that your implementation or fields have overridden the default of case-insensitive behavior.  The use of a function in a `where` clause generally prevents the use of indexes.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply. I need to check the performance if I just glue all the conditions with ORs one to other. From the execution plan I can see that then only one scan is used just like with the IN-clause. While for UNION ALL there are many scans. I thought that UNION ALL is more smart. I will measure the performance. Very stupid that I didn't do it in that way the first time. The only my concern is taht WHERE can become too long and SQL parser can sause delay. Thanks about the suggestion for the temp table too but I am collecting data from several tables it can be performance drag.

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe I assume the table has a very large number of rows in which case it is almost certainly the UPPER which is causing the speed issue because that means it can't properly use the indexes which you appeaar to have correctly set. Is the data stored really case-sensitive? - check db setting, by default it usually isn't in which case you can remove the UPPER.

If it IS case-sensitive then if the case of the stored names is consistent you can still remove the Upper and just use whatever the consistent upper/lower case name is e.g. Name = 'ProgB.H'

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. The whole database is case-sensitive. Yes it can contain very large number of rows but even for few thousend I can see a big delay. How can I check if my composite index is working if UPPER() is used? The index is defined over two or 3 columns, in this case - Name (ASC), Source (ASC). Is there some setting of the composite index making it explicitely case-insensitive and working f UPPER is used?

Comment: It's just not possible to use the index properly because it is in case-sensitive order so in effect it has to to a table scan and convert each name to upper in order to do the comparison. As I said you can still remove the UPPER if you can guarantee each name in the table is consistent in its use of case. Or can you rename them so they are consistent? Here is a link to view exceution plans http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071(v=sql.105).aspx